# How do I post an image using Koala gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, koala, koala-gem

I'm using the Koala gem to post images to the Facebook wall with the put_object method. The problem I'm having is that the images show up as thumbnails on the wall (with a caption) instead of the larger image that I'm expecting. When you click on the thumbnail, I'm expecting the photo to pop open in Facebook's photo viewer, but it simply directs me to the URL of the image I specified. This seems more like the behavior I'd expect when posting a link to the wall. I've also tried using post_picture with no success. Here is a screenshot of what I'm expecting: http://cl.ly/image/472a2H333z13

My stream permissions include the following:

```
read_stream,offline_access,manage_pages,publish_stream,create_event,rsvp_event,sms,user_photos,friends_about_me,friends_status,friends_activities,friends_likes,friends_interests,read_insights,friends_photos
```

The following code works but not as expected - here is a screenshot of how an image posted in using put_object appears on the timeline: http://cl.ly/image/1x3X1K0k2l2D

```
put_object('me', 'feed', :message => 'this is the message', :name => 'this is the caption', :picture => 'http://www.socialvolt.com/img/producttour/listen.png', :source => 'http://www.socialvolt.com/img/producttour/ssPublish.jpg')
```

This code doesn't work at all:

```
put_picture('me', 'feed', :message => 'this is the message', :name => 'this is the caption', :picture => 'http://www.socialvolt.com/img/producttour/listen.png', :source => 'http://www.socialvolt.com/img/producttour/ssPublish.jpg')
```

I also can't find any difference between :picture and :source.

Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code.

```
 graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(cookies[:acess_token])
 begin                  
   graph.put_picture(
                     "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/71317935/banners/coy_copper.jpg",
                     "image/png",
                     {:message => "introduces Some information"}
                   )
 rescue Exception => e
   render :text => e.message and return
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, you may need a larger photo. More specifically, I think the width needs to be **at least 480px**.

The images in your code seem to be less than 480px:
http://www.socialvolt.com/img/producttour/listen.png
http://www.socialvolt.com/img/producttour/ssPublish.jpg

This comes from experience with [User Generated Photos](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/usergeneratedphotos/). You're not really using Open Graph Actions, so I have no idea if Facebook applies the same rules for this to generic photo uploads.